# Popcorn- what's the best way to compare the fit non-linear models for data that is not very complex?

Tags: modeling, nonlinear-regression, pearson-r

I popped 7 bags of popcorn in 30 second increments and found the percentage of popped kernels in each time frame. [image]

I manipulated this data with sinusoidal, exponential, and cubic models. There is lots of debate surrounding the sufficiency of using r squared to comparing the goodness of fit for non-linear regression models. For data as simple as this, is r squared still not the best way to compare the fit of non-linear models? If not, is there something that might work better? Thanks :)

Comment: welcome, robert - nice experiment! What do you mean by "manipulated the data"? your results are percentages. A go-to way to analyze such data is logistic regression - did you try this? you would need the original counts (popped, and total number) for that.

Comment: With only 7 data points, you need to be very careful about overfitting, so, I think you want to use some kind of penalized model.  Or else pop a lot more popcorn!

Also, maybe I am missing something, but how could it be sinusoidal? The main characteristic of the sine is that it oscillates, your % keeps going up.

Comment: Just throwing a bunch of mean-functions at a tiny data set is not a good approach. Some thought is needed. You need a monotonic nondecreasing function. My first thought (without reference to your data, just based on having  popped corn before) would be a logistic function of log time.  However, variation in kernels means some will pop easily and some will never pop, so the model won't be particularly good; the true asymptote would be slightly  below 1 for one thing.

Comment: Over many years of listening to popcorn pop I have concluded that a Gaussian distribution was a decent approximation.  There is a theoretical basis--zeroth order kinetics--identical to that underlying radioactive decay.  This model works pretty well for these data, especially when estimated using weighted least squares (with weights proportional to $P(1-P)$). Unless you can propose a different theoretical model, you ought to use the Gaussian as a frame of reference (and something to be improved or modified) rather than fitting arbitrary functions.

Comment: The data distribution is sinusoindal or S-shaped. Metrics for a linear model could be compared with a nonlinear model appropriate for such shapes based on r square and accuracy (fit) as well as slope. Given the few data points, a nonlinear diffusion model such as Pearl or Gompertz would afford such a comparison with classic linear OLS. Such nonlinear model tutorials are all over Youtube.